# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from http://demo.tuleap.com

Tags: php, soap

```
$soap_option  = array(
'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
'exceptions' => 1,
'trace'      => 1
);

$client_login = new SoapClient($host_login, $soap_option);
$session_hash = $client_login->login($userName,$password)->session_hash;
$client_tracker = new SoapClient($host_tracker, $soap_option);
```

The connection was successful the first time, but it fails if I try one more time.

Comment: "The connection was success at first time,Failed if i try one more time" I don't see a second time in your code.

Comment: I refreshed the request at second time in URL

Comment: Hi,anyone have solution for this.

Comment: Also connection was success at once after restart the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below steps are helped me to resolve.
Step 1: Replace the second argument of a constructor SoapClient as

```
$soap_option  = array(
'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_DISK,
'exceptions' => 1,
'trace'      => 1
);
```

Step:2 clear the files in /tmp directory 
Step3: Restart the server 
Step4: Run the file on browser
Note:
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0);
This line should be called before create instance for SoapClient